# net.sf.json.JSONException

Tags: java, javascript, json, multidimensional-array, jsonexception

I converted a normal JavaScript `array` (which is in one JSP page), did a `JSON.stringify()` to that array and passed it across to another JSP as a parameter. In the other JSP, I'm reading it using `request.getParameter()`.

Now, while converting the string to a `JSONArray`, I'm getting an exception like this-

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: Missing value. at character 2 of [[\"111\", \"1.1.1.1\", \"111\", \"111\", \"111\"]]
at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:505)
        at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:377)
        at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromJSONTokener(JSONArray.java:1132)
        at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:125)
        at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:350)
        at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromJSONTokener(JSONArray.java:1132)
        at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromString(JSONArray.java:1198)
        at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:127)
        at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:137)
        at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:103)
        at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:84)
        at org.apache.jsp.pages.Handler_jsp._jspService(Handler_jsp.java:146)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:274)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:320)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1813)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

This is how my String from request.getParameter() looks like-

```
[[\"111\", \"1.1.1.1\", \"111\", \"111\", \"111\"]]
```

What does **`net.sf.json.JSONException: Missing value. at character 2 of [[\"111\", \"1.1.1.1\", \"111\", \"111\", \"111\"]]`** mean? And how do I deal with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. The reason it was throwing that exception was because it was expecting `"` instead of `\"` after `[[`. All I did was `[[\"111\", \"1.1.1.1\", \"111\", \"111\", \"111\"]].replaceAll("\\\"", "\"")`.